# How to skip a hostname from ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible, range, inventory

My ansible inventory file has the following entry

```
[non_prod_servers]
oracle[1:13]
```

How can I eliminate hosts "oracle7" and "oracle10" from the above specification, without having to create the following entries?

```
[non_prod_servers]
oracle[1:6]
oracle[8:9]
oracle[11:13]
```

Essentially, looking for an elegant solution than what I have come up with.

Thanks in advance.

FR

Comment: Use the relevant [pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) either as a `hosts:` target or as a `--limit` on the command line => `non_prod_servers:!oracle7:!oracle10`

Comment: Thanks. Can I somehow skip the two hosts from within the inventory file?

Comment: That's what [`meta: end_host`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) is for, as in: `- { meta: end_host, when: my_host_is_skipped | d(False) }` and then add the `my_host_is_skipped=True` in your inventory for the interesting hosts

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the functionality, you're looking for, is not available. You can use Python slicing inside the inventory. The inventory patterns do not apply inside the inventory file.

If you need it for automation, i.e. you want to control the process by a couple of variables the inventory and playbook below create the group dynamically

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[non_prod_servers]
localhost
[non_prod_servers:vars]
_name=oracle
_from=1
_to=13
_deny=[7,10]
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
---
- hosts: non_prod_servers
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ _name }}{{ item }}"
        groups: non_prod_servers_dyn
      loop: "{{ range(_from, _to + 1)|difference(_deny) }}"

- hosts: non_prod_servers_dyn
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml

PLAY [non_prod_servers] *************************************************

TASK [add_host] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)
ok: [localhost] => (item=4)
ok: [localhost] => (item=5)
ok: [localhost] => (item=6)
ok: [localhost] => (item=8)
ok: [localhost] => (item=9)
ok: [localhost] => (item=11)
ok: [localhost] => (item=12)
ok: [localhost] => (item=13)

PLAY [non_prod_servers_dyn] **********************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [oracle1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - oracle1
  - oracle2
  - oracle3
  - oracle4
  - oracle5
  - oracle6
  - oracle8
  - oracle9
  - oracle11
  - oracle12
  - oracle13
```